# Why program fails when started using /lib/ld-linux.so.2?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, glibc

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo qqq'
qqq
$ /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/bash -c 'echo qqq'
/bin/bash: xmalloc: ../bash/variables.c:2176: cannot allocate 3 bytes (8192 bytes allocated)
```

Why this happens (zsh4, python works well in this use case)? Can it be caused by "prelink"?

Comment: Do you mean LD_PRELINK?

Comment: No, `prelink (8)          - prelink ELF shared libraries and binaries to speed up startup time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by [barti-ddu](https://superuser.com/users/59796/barti-ddu), it is likely [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/452175)

The one of workarounds is to disable kernel allocation randomization:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Comment: i wish you accepted your answer so that it stays on top ;) Concerning _va space randomization_ it is better (if possible) to upgrade the kernel, since disabling it is a security risk. Anyway, glad you've resolved the loader issue, good luck.

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in 22 hours". You can re-post it as your answer, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to call 64-bit binary with 32-bit lib on amd64 architecture; in my case:

```
ls -l /lib/ld-linux.so.2
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> /lib32/ld-linux.so.2
```

Comment: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so`

Comment: @Vi.: and the output of `file /bin/bash` is... ?

Comment: `/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0xb9a715b5137f1d8d532103e0f7f7a288039bf7f7, stripped`

Comment: @Vi.: hmm, i was pretty sure, that you've mixed 32/64 bit components; what does `strace -i /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/bash -c 'echo qqq'` produce?

Comment: strace: http://sprunge.us/CiOH ltrace: http://sprunge.us/OcQQ .

Comment: @Vi.: nothing criminal except the crash itself :/ however, this (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/452175) report may be related